# Typescript Project References common dependency reference

Tags: typescript, monorepo

This is basically a repost of my https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh/project-references-demo/issues/10 in case the busy maintainer is less available to comment.

There seems to be a lot of confusion on the web still about how to correctly and effectively use Typescript Project References, especially in monorepo scenarios.  I'm trying to assemble such a prototype for myself and I'm running into issues getting builds to work.

I figured @RyanCavanaugh's example would be the best reference.  I was surprised to find that I get build errors with the simple addition of a shared reference.  Perhaps I just made a stupid mistake/omission?

I start with his zoo example which has references from zoo -> animals -> core, and I merely add a reference directly from zoo -> core.  But then `npm build` generates many errors, starting with:

```
animals/index.ts:1:20 - error TS6059: File 'C:/code/project-references-demo/animals/animal.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/code/project-references-demo/zoo'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

| import Animal from './animal';
```

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Errors came because you use inecessary dots in import and out of project folder 
Try to reduce dots: import {Dog, createDog} from 'animals' . The 'index' also unnecessary if name file is index.ts

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: And also I see that filenames absent in tsconfig.json

Comment: Write in tsconfig.json your new file: core.ts

Comment: There is no new file.  There is no expectation of drastic changes for such a simple addition (without a proportional justification).  It's a simple extension of a _working_ sample.

Comment: Can you share your project from git?

Comment: https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh/project-references-demo plus the few screenshotted delta above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix for screenshot:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig-base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../lib/zoo",
    "rootDir": "."
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../animals",
      
    },
    {
      "path": "../core"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am not able to replicate your success and I also don't understand why these changes would be expected to fix it.

Comment: tsconfig-base.json is just part of the ts config, so an extended tsconfig.json is needed

Comment: Also, I am not able to replicate your failure, too

Comment: I can put my version in github if needed

Comment: if you cannot replicate the original failure, then why is this change recommended?

Comment: I updated my answer, sorry I forgot about your screenshot

Comment: That is it, thank you!   I accidently added multiple members instead of multiple array elements.